# ggplot2 horizontal barplot with gradient color fill and Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale, geom-bar

I am trying to create horizontal bar plot and would like to fill bars using a color gradient, white for lowest value and darkest for highest value.

First of all I created figure 1 through the follow script. The columns inform the frequency of each species):

```
Dataset <- read.csv(file = "dados.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
attach(Dataset)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie,M1_sava, fill = momento)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow=1) + # place the factors in separate facets
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +     # make the bars
  coord_flip() +                  # flip the axes so the test names can be horizontal  
  theme_bw(base_size=10)          # use a black-and-white theme with set font size
```

However I would like to leave the bars with gradient coloring, as in figure 2 and for this I wrote the next script, but the error message appeared:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

```
ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie,M1_sava, fill = momento)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow=1) + # place the factors in separate facets
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +     # make the bars
  coord_flip() +                  # flip the axes so the test names can be horizontal  
  geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white",high = "green") +
  theme_bw(base_size=10)          # use a black-and-white theme with set font size
```

[image]

Data:

```
specie  momento M1_sava
S1  M1  1,00
S2  M1  0,86
S3  M1  1,00
S4  M1  1,00
S5  M1  1,00
S6  M1  0,74
S7  M1  0,39
S8  M1  0,83
S9  M1  0,83
S10 M1  0,00
S11 M1  0,70
S12 M1  0,11
S13 M1  1,00
S14 M1  0,00
S15 M1  0,00
S16 M1  0,00
S17 M1  0,00
S18 M1  0,83
S19 M1  0,00
S20 M1  0,00
S21 M1  0,00
S22 M1  0,00
S23 M1  0,00
S24 M1  0,04
S25 M1  0,00
S26 M1  0,00
S1  M2  0,33
S2  M2  0,86
S3  M2  0,39
S4  M2  0,02
S5  M2  0,07
S6  M2  0,02
S7  M2  0,87
S8  M2  0,06
S9  M2  0,63
S10 M2  0,33
S11 M2  0,91
S12 M2  0,67
S13 M2  0,18
S14 M2  0,08
S15 M2  0,00
S16 M2  0,00
S17 M2  0,00
S18 M2  0,00
S19 M2  0,08
S20 M2  0,00
S21 M2  0,04
S22 M2  0,00
S23 M2  0,00
S24 M2  0,00
S25 M2  0,00
S26 M2  0,00
S1  M3  0,04
S2  M3  0,32
S3  M3  0,02
S4  M3  0,00
S5  M3  0,00
S6  M3  0,00
S7  M3  0,96
S8  M3  0,06
S9  M3  0,18
S10 M3  0,33
S11 M3  0,63
S12 M3  1,00
S13 M3  0,00
S14 M3  0,94
S15 M3  0,17
S16 M3  0,00
S17 M3  0,41
S18 M3  0,04
S19 M3  0,44
S20 M3  0,17
S21 M3  0,02
S22 M3  0,00
S23 M3  0,00
S24 M3  0,00
S25 M3  0,00
S26 M3  0,00
S1  M4  0,00
S2  M4  0,00
S3  M4  0,00
S4  M4  0,00
S5  M4  0,00
S6  M4  0,00
S7  M4  0,89
S8  M4  0,00
S9  M4  0,03
S10 M4  0,22
S11 M4  0,41
S12 M4  0,46
S13 M4  0,00
S14 M4  0,81
S15 M4  0,39
S16 M4  0,70
S17 M4  0,70
S18 M4  0,00
S19 M4  0,87
S20 M4  0,91
S21 M4  0,33
S22 M4  0,37
S23 M4  0,24
S24 M4  0,15
S25 M4  0,00
S26 M4  0,00
```

Comment: Try removing the `geom_bar(stat="identity") + ` line from your code. It's still inheriting the top level aesthetic mapping `fill = momento` (i.e. discrete scale), which clashes with `scale_fill_gradient2` (i.e. continuous scale).

Comment: Thank you Z.lin, however with the follow script the erro message appears:  Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
 
ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie,M1_sava)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow=1) + # place the factors in separate facets
  geom_bar() +     # make the bars
  coord_flip() +                  # flip the axes so the test names can be horizontal  
  geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white",high = "green") +
  theme_bw(base_size=10)

Answer (score 0):

As @Z.Lin wrote - you should remove `geom_bar(stat="identity") +` but keep `fill = momento`:

```
Dataset <- read.table(text = "specie  momento M1_sava
                  S1  M1  1.00
                  S2  M1  0.86
                  S3  M1  1.00
                  S4  M1  1.00
                  S5  M1  1.00
                  S6  M1  0.74
                  S7  M1  0.39
                  S8  M1  0.83
                  S9  M1  0.83
                  S10 M1  0.00
                  S11 M1  0.70
                  S12 M1  0.11
                  S13 M1  1.00
                  S14 M1  0.00
                  S15 M1  0.00
                  S16 M1  0.00
                  S17 M1  0.00
                  S18 M1  0.83
                  S19 M1  0.00
                  S20 M1  0.00
                  S21 M1  0.00
                  S22 M1  0.00
                  S23 M1  0.00
                  S24 M1  0.04
                  S25 M1  0.00
                  S26 M1  0.00
                  S1  M2  0.33
                  S2  M2  0.86
                  S3  M2  0.39
                  S4  M2  0.02
                  S5  M2  0.07
                  S6  M2  0.02
                  S7  M2  0.87
                  S8  M2  0.06
                  S9  M2  0.63
                  S10 M2  0.33
                  S11 M2  0.91
                  S12 M2  0.67
                  S13 M2  0.18
                  S14 M2  0.08
                  S15 M2  0.00
                  S16 M2  0.00
                  S17 M2  0.00
                  S18 M2  0.00
                  S19 M2  0.08
                  S20 M2  0.00
                  S21 M2  0.04
                  S22 M2  0.00
                  S23 M2  0.00
                  S24 M2  0.00
                  S25 M2  0.00
                  S26 M2  0.00
                  S1  M3  0.04
                  S2  M3  0.32
                  S3  M3  0.02
                  S4  M3  0.00
                  S5  M3  0.00
                  S6  M3  0.00
                  S7  M3  0.96
                  S8  M3  0.06
                  S9  M3  0.18
                  S10 M3  0.33
                  S11 M3  0.63
                  S12 M3  1.00
                  S13 M3  0.00
                  S14 M3  0.94
                  S15 M3  0.17
                  S16 M3  0.00
                  S17 M3  0.41
                  S18 M3  0.04
                  S19 M3  0.44
                  S20 M3  0.17
                  S21 M3  0.02
                  S22 M3  0.00
                  S23 M3  0.00
                  S24 M3  0.00
                  S25 M3  0.00
                  S26 M3  0.00
                  S1  M4  0.00
                  S2  M4  0.00
                  S3  M4  0.00
                  S4  M4  0.00
                  S5  M4  0.00
                  S6  M4  0.00
                  S7  M4  0.89
                  S8  M4  0.00
                  S9  M4  0.03
                  S10 M4  0.22
                  S11 M4  0.41
                  S12 M4  0.46
                  S13 M4  0.00
                  S14 M4  0.81
                  S15 M4  0.39
                  S16 M4  0.70
                  S17 M4  0.70
                  S18 M4  0.00
                  S19 M4  0.87
                  S20 M4  0.91
                  S21 M4  0.33
                  S22 M4  0.37
                  S23 M4  0.24
                  S24 M4  0.15
                  S25 M4  0.00
                  S26 M4  0.00", header = T)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Dataset, aes(specie, M1_sava, fill = momento)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ momento, nrow = 1) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = M1_sava)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "green") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 10)
```

Is this desired output?

[image]

Comment: Hi Adela, Thank you! I want exactely this graphic, but I've tried the script that you and @z.lin said and it didn't work. Did you use this exactely script? Cause I'm trying with this one and the error message is still appearing

Comment: I added also uploading of data and library. This is my complete code. Maybe you have some old version of `ggplot2`. Try to update it.